# Community "White screen" intermittent problem in early morning hours

Tags: community, experience-cloud, publisher, experience-builder-page

I have a Community that has been running for about 4 years.  During the past couple of months, my users have been experiencing the "white screen" problem when visiting the site.  The problem is intermittent and appears in the early morning hours of Eastern time.  I have an open case on this with Salesforce but am not getting anywhere.  Below are times that I have documented it has happened.  To resolve the problem, I go into internal Salesforce, Digital Experiences, All Sites and then into Builder of my Community.  I immediately click Publish.  While I haven't made any changes to the site, it does publish.  Interestingly, immediately after I hit publish, I refresh the website in another browser tab & it displays correctly before the site finishes publishing.  When I look at Change History in Site Builder, I can see that "Site Info" has changed although I haven't made any changes.  I have noticed that "Site Info" is not something that always appears when I publish for other reasons.  However, it is always listed as having changes when we experience the "white screen" problem.  Salesforce hasn't been able to tell me what would change that would cause "Site Info" to appear in the Change History list.  When the "white screen" happens, it is for all users in all browsers.

Friday - 7/16 - noticed at 5 am
Tuesday - 7/28 - noticed at 9:10 am
Thursday – 8/12 – noticed at 9:00 am
Thursday – 8/19 – noticed at 8:30 am
Tuesday - 8/24 - noticed at 5 am
Thursday - 9/9 - noticed at 8:30 am - was available earlier in day at 2:00 am

I have also noticed the problem occur between 1 am Eastern but resolves itself by 1:30 am.  I haven't checked it a lot at this time because I try to sleep.  However, it happened at the same time two days last week when I monitored it.  In this 1 - 1:30 situation, It resolved itself without my publishing.

I only have one active community.  I am not using CDN.

Comment: what's your setup like? Are you using your own CDN, how is your [custom domain served](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_domain_config_options.htm&type=5), do you have multiple communities for this org?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves  I have one active Community.  I am not using CDN.